# Parallel for doesn't do all records

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I am processing +100000 rows and implemented Parallel. This for faster processing.

logic behaviour would be : 100000 records which has 85000 groupId meaning MyItems should hold 85000 records.

This is not the case... i end up with an amount different then 85000

The process goes as follows:

Get all values from DB

Get all the ID's (not row ID's, but a groupId) inside an Array of integers

process the groupId's

```
var myItems = new List<MyItem>(IDCounter.Length);

Parallel.For(0, IDCounter.Length, (i, loopState) =>
{
  if(!SomeParameter)
    loopState.Stop();

  var records = (from m in AllValues where m.GroupId == IDCounter[i] select m).ToList();

  var recordList = new List<MyRecords>();

  for(var j = 0; j<records.Count; j++)
  {
    recordList.Add(new MyRecord{Text = records[j].OtherValue});
  }

  myItems.Add(new MyItem(Text = records[0].SomeValue, List = recordList));

});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the type of `myItems`? f it's a `List<T>`, then you're accessing it from multiple threasd, despite it not being threadsafe. Also, this looks like pseudo-code at the moment: `new MyItem(Text = records[0].SomeValue, List = l)`. It's much easier to help you if you post *real* code - ideally a short but complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I fail to see how this is more efficient than sequential algorithm since you always process the full list of items.

Comment: @JonSkeet; thought i provided a short but usable real code, it's not very different from what i have

Comment: @Schuere: Look at the piece of code I highlighted... what do you thinkg `List = l` does? It looks like it's trying to assign to a variable or property called `List`. What you've got is half way between creating an anonymous type instance and specifying named arguments to the constructor. Even leaving that aside, this is clearly a long way from complete at the moment.

Comment: Oh, and I'd be very surprised if `records.Count` worked without calling `ToList` somewhere. Fundamentally, this is clearly *not* the code you're running.

Comment: @JonSkeet, true that, but that's not where the problem lies, wrote the code in +- 2 minutes; I did altered it btw :)

Comment: @Schuere: So you took about 2 minutes to write the code for the question, thus *wasting* the time of everyone else who's been looking at it. If you can't be bothered to write a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, why should anyone else be bothered to help you? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints.

Comment: Well @JonSkeet, that's where the edit button is for! And as I recall, being rude doesn't solve problems either. I did follow your comments and did edit the question. As far as I know, I did what you asked, your rant however is not appreciated!

Comment: I can't edit the code to provide information I don't have - and I don't see "there's an edit button" as an excuse for laziness. You did *not* do what I requested, which was to provide a short but complete exmaple demonstrating the problem. If the example had been complete, I'd have been able to copy, paste, compile and run it with no other effort involved. The more effort you put into asking a great question, the sooner you're likely to get a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure that you do not add items to the list at the same time you can use a [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

> The `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace provides several thread-safe collection classes that should be used in place of the corresponding types in the `System.Collections`  and `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces whenever multiple threads are accessing the collection concurrently.

One example would be to use a [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) since you have no guarantee which order the items will be added.

> Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

Another way to do this would be to use a lock when adding to the list to make sure only one item is added at any given time.

Comment: In scenarios where list lock contention becomes an issue a superior version of "use a lock when adding to the list" is using thread-local state and "finally". `Parallel.For` provides a number of overloads for that, where each thread gets its own `List<T>` to add to, and they're all put together inside the "finally" delegate to produce a single collection (MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Didn't know this, will take a look!

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `myItems.Add` multiple times concurrently. Make sure it's thread-safe.